# Installing 64 bit PyCharm on Windows 10

Tags: python, 64-bit, pycharm

I have a Windows 10 Home 64-bit installed on a x64 laptop. I also have Python 3.4.3 Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit) (default, Mar  6 2015, 12:06:10) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] installed as well as 64-bit versions of Java, Firefox and Tortoise.

For some reason when I run the PyCharm installer it only offers me the option of a 32 bit installation (rather irritatingly it doesn't even allow me to download a 64 bit installer from the website). Of course 32-bit PyCharm can't interact with 64-bit Tortoise.

So, how can I force PyCharm to install the 64-bit version or do I have to downgrade Tortoise, Java, Firefox etc. to 32-bit? It really shouldn't be this difficult!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [help article](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under)from Intellij. The Windows version has a 32bit java JRE download bundled with the installer. If you want to run a 64 bit version you have to install the 64bit JDK yourself as explained in the article.